# A little bit nasty double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I have difficulty calculating the following double integral:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2-2mxy+y^2+h^2}\text{d}x\text{d}y$$
where $m\in[-1,1],h\in(0,\infty)$ are constants.

---

What I've tried with the help of others:

\begin{align*}
I&=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\sec\theta}r\cdot\sqrt{(1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta)r^2+h^2}\text{d}r\text{d}\theta
\end{align*}
let $a=1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta$, then the inner part looks like this：
$$\int r\cdot\sqrt{ar^2+h^2}\text{d}r$$
let $u=ar^2+h^2$, then the inner part should be:
$$\frac1{2a}\int\sqrt{u}\text{d}u=\frac1{3a}u^{\frac32}=\frac1{3a}(ar^2+h^2)^{\frac32}$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\sec\theta}r\sqrt{ar^2+h^2}\text{d}r
&=\frac1{3a}[(a\sec^2\theta+h^2)^\frac32-h^3 ]\\
&=\frac{(\tan^2\theta-2m\tan\theta+h^2+1)^\frac32-h^3}{3-6m\sin\theta\cos\theta}
\end{align*}
So,
$$\frac23\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{(\tan^2\theta-2m\tan\theta+h^2+1)^\frac32-h^3}{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta}\text{d}\theta$$
But I have no idea how to deal with:
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{(\tan^2\theta-2m\tan\theta+h^2+1)^{\frac32}}{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta}\text{d}\theta$$

---

Update:

Thanks to @sreysus, we change it to
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sqrt{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta+h^2}}{\cos^3\theta}\text{d}\theta+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{h^2\sqrt{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta+h^2}}{\cos\theta-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta}\text{d}\theta$$

What I've tried:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sqrt{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta+h^2}}{\cos^3\theta}\text{d}\theta
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sqrt{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta+h^2}}{\cos\theta}\text{d}\tan\theta\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sqrt{(1+h^2)\sec^2\theta-2m\tan\theta}\text{d}\tan\theta\\
&=\int_0^1\sqrt{(1+h^2)(1+u^2)-2mu}\text{d}u
\end{align*}
Though it's complicated, I've worked this part out (too complicated to put it here)

---

So I got stuck how to evaluate this part:
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{h^2\sqrt{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta+h^2}}{\cos\theta-2m\sin\theta\cos^2\theta}\text{d}\theta$$
where $m\in[-1,1],h\in(0,+\infty)$ are constants.

---

Update:
[image]

I'm now wondering how to evaluate integral in the form of
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+p}}{x^2+q}\text{d}x$$

Thanks everyone, I've solved it.

Comment: Are you missing an $m$ in the last expression on the numerator?

Comment: @sreysus, oh, I didn't notice that, I've edited it, thanks.

Comment: Substituting $(u,v)=\left(\dfrac{x-y}{\sqrt2},\dfrac{x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)$ to rotate the square and exploiting symmetry in $u$ gives$$2\int_0^{\tfrac1{\sqrt2}}\int_u^{\sqrt2-u}\sqrt{h^2+(1+m)u^2+(1-m)v^2}\,dv\,du$$which may be somewhat easier to compute

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a complete answer, but it was too big to put it in the comments.

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{(\tan^2 \theta - 2m\tan \theta + h^2 + 1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{1-2m\sin \theta \cos \theta}$$
$$=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{((\tan\theta - m)^2-m^2 + h^2 + 1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{1-2m\sin \theta \cos \theta}$$
$(\tan \theta - m)^2$ becomes $\frac{\sin^2 \theta + m\cos^2 \theta -2m\sin \theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta}$ in the numerator.

$$\begin{align*}\\&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{(\frac{1 -2m\sin \theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta} + h^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{1-2m\sin \theta \cos \theta}\\&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{(\frac{1 -2m\sin \theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta} + h^2)\sqrt{\frac{1 -2m\sin \theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta} + h^2}}{1-2m\sin \theta \cos \theta}\\&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \big(\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta} + \frac{h^2}{1-2m\sin \theta \cos \theta}\big)\sqrt{\frac{1 -2m\sin \theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta} + h^2}\\&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \big(\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}\big)\sqrt{\frac{1 -2m\sin \theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta} + h^2} + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{h^2}{1-2m\sin \theta \cos \theta}\sqrt{\frac{1 -2m\sin \theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta} + h^2}\end{align*}$$

Now, we have
$$=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \big(\frac{1}{\cos^3\theta}\big)\sqrt{1 -2m\sin \theta\cos\theta + h^2} + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{h^2}{\cos\theta-2m\sin \theta \cos^2 \theta}\sqrt{1 -2m\sin \theta\cos\theta + h^2}$$

I managed to remove the tangents. The first integral seems fine, but it's the second that worries me. Can you take it from here, possibly with integration by parts, or did I make the problem worse?

---

**Edit.** After a while, I still wasn't able to figure the last integral out. However, with the help of WolframAlpha, I found that the last integral simplifies nicely.

Let $a = 1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta$. We have:

$$\begin{align*}\\&=h^2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\cos\theta}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta +h^2}}{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta}
\\&=\ln|\tan\theta+\sec\theta|\cdot\frac{\sqrt{a +h^2}}{a} - \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln|\tan\theta+\sec\theta|\cdot\frac{m\cos (2\theta)}{(1-2m\sin(2\theta))^{\frac{3}{2}}}\text{d}\theta
\\&=\ln|\tan\theta+\sec\theta|\cdot\frac{\sqrt{a +h^2}}{a}+\frac{\ln|\tan\theta+\sec\theta|}{\sqrt{1-m\sin(2\theta)}}-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sec^2\theta+\tan\theta\sec\theta}{\big(\tan\theta+\sec\theta\big)\big(\sqrt{1-m\sin(2\theta)}\big)}
\\&=\ln|\tan\theta+\sec\theta|\cdot\frac{\sqrt{a +h^2}}{a}+\frac{\ln|\tan\theta+\sec\theta|}{\sqrt{1-m\sin(2\theta)}}-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sec\theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin(2\theta)}}\text{d}\theta\end{align*}$$

This is not a final answer because, as of writing this, I am very busy, so I was unable to complete this very interesting integral. Hopefully, after you find a way to deal with this last integral, you should be able to plug in $\frac{\pi}{4}$ for $\theta$ and subtract with the $\theta =0$ version of the expression.

Comment: I've tried a little, it seems that though it's complicated, maybe it can work. Maybe I can put what I've tried in the question updates. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea on the second integral, either...

Comment: I edited my answer, tell me if you find any errors.

Comment: I haven't checked yet, but I did work out the last integral, I'm now organizing all the steps, thanks!

Comment: I wonder if you missed a $\cos^2\theta$ term after $h^2$ at the step after "Now, we have"...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think it was the formatting, but actually the expression after $h^2$ continues to the next line